# How do I use github tags to create downloads for my project?

Tags: tags, download, github

How do I use github tags to create downloads for my project?

Are there any special keywords or formats that need to be used? I've created a tag and pushed the latest version but it's not showing on github, nor has a a download been created (the one there is a manual upload by me).

I'm using GitX locally.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/gingerbeardman/monkey.tmbundle

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Tags aren't pushed by default; try a `git push --tags <remote>`. That will sync all of your tags. If you want to push a single tag, use `git push <remote> <tagname>`.

Comment: @matt thanks - also check out the Github [docs on working with remotes](http://help.github.com/remotes/) which has a few other tricks you might need.