# Using GitHub as a code repository for tutorial project

Tags: github

I`m planning a project, and was wondering if it would be a good idea to use GitHub as a code repository for the project.

The project is just me creating a single application step by step. In fact, it is more like me learning how to do it, and documenting my process, and letting other people tag along.

So step 1 could be setting up the project, step 2 how to organize the files, step 2 connecting to the database, step 3 how to do the UI etc. (btw. this is not how the project is set up)

The documentation would consist of a website with articles for each step and along with each step I want to enable the visitor to download/view the code for the project to the point where we are in the process.

I don`t know how top use GitHub, but I was planning on learning it as well. Would GitHub be a good way to share the code for a project like this?

Is there a way in GitHub to take snapshots, like step 1, step 2, etc., or would it be better to use branches or forks for this?

A nice feature would be the ability to correct the entire chain of steps if I find a typo in step one.

Does anyone know of an existing GitHub project that is set up in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GitHub, provided you push also **tags** for each significant steps.
(as explained in "[How do I use github tags to create downloads for my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312651/how-do-i-use-github-tags-to-create-downloads-for-my-project)")

That way, you can provide download links for each of those tags, even for the readers who don't have Git installed.

See "[All of your downloads. One big button.](https://github.com/blog/729-all-of-your-downloads-one-big-button)"

[image: downlaods]

Comment: Will the use of tags enable me to do edits in step 1 later on in the project and cascade the edits to the other steps?

Comment: @user1182478 no, that would be branches, that would would start, conveniently enough, from your tag. And with GitHub, you can *also* download a branch HEAD too, without Git locally installed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978954/add-binary-distribution-to-githubs-download-link/6978988#6978988).

Comment: @user1182478 As I explain in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753703/should-a-release-candidate-be-immutable/13753753#13753753, tags are immutable and reference a fixed point in history (which can be the starting point of each step evolution). Branches are for mutable history.

Comment: @user1182478 once you manage those branches, fix a bug in stepn would involve rebasing all the other subsequent one: stepn+1 on top of stepn, stepn+2 on top of (new because rebased) stepn+1, etc. I prefer that to the classic cherry-picking (illustrated in http://technosophos.com/content/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches)